# How to prove if a list is sorted if any two consecutive elements are sorted?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, sorting

To check if a list is sorted, a typical approach is to check every element and its next element, and see if they are sorted. Intuitively, I understand it is correct. But is there a more mathematical or rigorous way to prove this? Thanks

Comment: Well yes, transitivity of order and the finiteness of the list implies this by induction. If the list is infinite, this may not be true.

Comment: It cannot get simpler than that. Maybe, if a < b and b < c then a < c, is something you are looking for? Or are you talking about the invariance in the approach?

Comment: @Gray_Rhino edit: yes this is close to what I am looking for. I read some more about proving transitivity on relation, now I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks! I was confused about the proof of transitivity and how to use it here, now I understand.